# Which function should I choose to find roots using scipy?

Tags: python, scipy

In `scipy.optimise` module, there are many different functions to find roots of a function (brentq, brenth, ridder, bisect, newton). However, I doesn't give mush information about what are the characteristics of each method. How can I determine which one is the more suitable for my needs? Which one should I chose?

In other words, what kind of optimization each function is better at?

Comment: Have you looked up the corresponding algorithms on Wikipedia? Have you simply tried them out with your functions?

Comment: What are the needs for which you're interested in knowing which functions are most suitable?

Comment: What I'd like to know is, in a generic point of view, what is the use of each function.